# One query issue i am getting

Tags: mysql

```
select distinct mlj.emp_id,mlj.name, concat_ws(' - ',main_reason, sub_reason) as 
       reason_for_leaving, comments_of_exit_interviewer, interviewer_name 
from my_exit 
left join 
     (select a.emp_id, concat_ws(' ',name,surname) as name, function,
             ref_grade, reportingto, main_function, DESIGNATION, region,
             date_format (submitted_on, '%d-%b-%Y') as dor 
      from employee a, my_exit b 
      where a.emp_id = b.emp_id  
            and BASE_LOCATION in ('Bangalore','Bangalore Corporate Office',
                                  'SA Beijing','SA Singapore','SA Sydney')) as mlj 
on mlj.emp_id = my_exit.emp_id 
left join 
     (select reporting_manager_empid, 
             round( abs( datediff(date_of_join, last_working_day))/360,2)
             as work_exp, date_format(last_working_day,'%d-%b-%Y') as lwd,
             typeexit, a.emp_id 
      from employee a, resignationForm b 
      where a.emp_id = b.emp_id  
      and BASE_LOCATION in ('Bangalore', 'Bangalore Corporate Office',
                            'SA Beijing','SA Singapore','SA Sydney')) as rlj 
on my_exit.emp_id = rlj.emp_id 
left join
     (select a.emp_id, q33, comments_of_exit_interviewer, interviewer_name
      from my_exit a, ext_intererview_ans b 
      where a.emp_id = b.emp_id) as slr 
on my_exit.emp_id = slr.emp_id 
   and slr.emp_id is not null 
where mlj.name is not null  
left join immcf on resignationForm.emp_id = immcf.emp_id 
where immcf.submittedby is null and date(submitted_on)>='2018-01-01' 
order by date(submitted_on);
```

Query is failing with some issues.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left join immcf on resignationForm.emp_id=immcf.emp_id' at line 1

Comment: Have you tried what the error is suggesting?

Comment: it is suggesting error near last left join statement, but i am not able to figure out anythimg.

Comment: You sure the columns and tables are named correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple `WHERE` clauses, which is not allowed. And the `WHERE` clause must be written after all `JOIN` and `FROM` clauses. You have the order `WHERE`, `LEFT JOIN`, `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing left join after Where clause.
First, you need to write all joins and then write Where clause.

```
"....where mlj.name is not null  left join immcf on resi...."
```